# Displaying overlapping polyline segments as multiple lines with offsets

Tags: leaflet, line, overlapping-features, visualisation, offset

Selecting which polyline is displayed on top in case of segment overlaps seems to be quite a FAQ, however, I would like to find a way to display overlapping polyline segments side-by-side, i.e. as multiple lines separated by offsets, similar to how Google Transit displays branching transit services.

[image: Google Transit]

Is there a Leaflet library that does that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there appears to be one called [Polyline Offset](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineOffset) which should allow you to control the rendering of polylines.

There's a [demo here](http://bbecquet.github.io/Leaflet.PolylineOffset/examples/example.html) and a screen shot of one of the other demos:-

[image]